# My friend can't join my minecraft world

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

We have always been able to play on my world, Me on my xbox account but on minecraft PE, and her on her xbox with xbox live. but recently she can't join my world but I can join hers. The only thing that I've changed at all is that I am now at my grandma's house instead of mine, but I'm still on Wi-Fi and I can join her world but she can't join mine. She has xbox live, nothing else has changed but location.

Comment: What error does do they get?

Comment: sometimes the world doesn't even show up to join it, and sometimes it says "Unable to connect to world"

Comment: do you know why it's happening?

Comment: Not entirely sure. I'll try looking for a possible solution.

Comment: Interesting question, maybe she has not updated her xbox minecraft to the latest version?

Comment: She's looking at her version right now.... there aren't any updates, but her version is 1.12.1.

Comment: I also have 1.12.1

Comment: We are having the same problem again today, yesterday it ended up working after my sister playing on LAN left but we tried the same thing today and it didn't work. Something about restricted skins maybe?